# Convert response string to object

Tags: javascript

I want this response:
`"socials": "Whatsapp_phone: 3413536723,Instagram: agusmac1,Linkedin: agusmac,Facebook: agusmac40"`

to be something like:

```
 socials={
Whatsapp: 3413536723,
Instagram: agusmac1,
Linkedin: agusmac,
Facebook: agusmac20}
```

ive tried JSON parse but i cant make it work

Comment: can you share the code of your call and how you handle the response so we can better help you?

Comment: Who/what ever produces that response should be fired...

Comment: is this data coming from a restful API? if not what is the source, cause you can send a json object from a restful api directly so when you receive the response its already and object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first parse the string into an object by wrapping the string in curly braces and using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Then, you can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the resulting object's `socials` property by a comma, split each individual item by a colon (with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)), then use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const str = `"socials": "Whatsapp_phone: 3413536723,Instagram: agusmac1,Linkedin: agusmac,Facebook: agusmac40"`

const obj = JSON.parse('{' + str + '}')
obj.socials = Object.fromEntries(obj.socials.split(",").map(e => e.split(":")))

console.log(obj)
```

If you want the value to be trimmed, you can use [`String.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```js
const str = `"socials": "Whatsapp_phone: 3413536723,Instagram: agusmac1,Linkedin: agusmac,Facebook: agusmac40"`

const obj = JSON.parse('{' + str + '}')
obj.socials = Object.fromEntries(obj.socials.split(",").map(e => (arr = e.split(":"), arr[1] = arr[1].trim(), arr)))

console.log(obj)
```